# Update component' when it's descendant changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an React/Redux app that works with "handlers" stored in Redux store and React components that are connectet to those handlers. These handlers are saved in a normalized flat structure and reffer to each other with unique id's.

What I want to do is to update a react element whenever any of his descendants update it's model in store.

```
// Redux state
const state = {
  h1: { name: "1", child: "h2" },
  h2: { name: "2", child: "h3" },
  h3: { name: "3", child: null }
};

// Helper function
const GetName = h => (h.child ? `${GetName(state[h.child])} in ${h.name}` : h.name);

// Component.jsx
class Handler extends React.Component {
  render = () => (
    <div>
      <div>Component {this.props.model.name} ({GetName(this.props.model))}</div>
      {this.props.model.child && <Handler id={this.props.model.child} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(
  Handler,
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    model: state[ownProps.id]
  })
);
```

Here is a simplified example of my code. The output here should look something like this:

```
Component 1 (3 in 2 in 1)
Component 2 (3 in 2)
Component 3 ()
```

In my code the GetName function is more complex, but the basic idea is that it builds the "name" of the handler. Now my proble is that f.e. when I update the third handler the first handler's name does not update since react didn't update it's component.

Is there a way to tell react that that component should be updated whenever state of descending handlers is changed or is there other simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace your `GetName` helper function with [reselect selector](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#creating-a-memoized-selector).
To make the reselect working here, you need to transform the recursion in your `GetName` helper into iteration first ([e.g. something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)).